# How to detect muonic hydrogen?

Tags: particle-physics, particle-detectors

I was wondering how can we detect if a muonic hydrogen is produced!
Let's imagine we have a beam made of (u-). These particles enter a proton chamber. If the particles are slow enough to fall in the proton orbit and produce muonic hydrogen how can we prove that?
I thought it might be possible using the bremsstrahlung made because of the reduction of muon's speed BUT a muon that bounces of a proton may also produce bremsstrahlung even though there was no muonic hydrogen produced,so it's not perfect enough.
Can anyone guide on finding a way to prove that a muonic hydrogen is produced?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The naively obvious thing to do is spectroscopy.

The spectroscopic signature of atomic decay in muonic hydrogen is similar to that of ordinary hydrogen, but shifted due to the different reduced mass. So observe the system in the IR, visible and UV to determine if that spectrum is present.

Comment: they even propose experiments to see the hyperfine splitting in muonic hydrogen http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1748-0221/11/05/P05007/meta